# Want to display total percent completed on home screen according to swiped card ID

Tags: ios, swift, swipe

In my app i am swiping the cards left or right and when all cards are finished swiping it takes me to the score screen where it shows the total percent answer i.e 30% or 40% etc..i want to display that score to the home screen according to respective card id whichever is swiped. my score screen is below:

[score screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9caR.png)

i want to display in home screen like this in the image below:
[home screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zhzuq.png)

the problem is when i swipe the other card category cards and then display the percentage score into home screen, the previously added score to previous category is gone. i want to show respective card score i.e lets say i swiped the food category cards, displayed the score and then swiped the vegetable cards then display the score. i want that the two categories card score should be displayed and so on. I think everytime i swipe the card try to show the score on home screen, then its being replaced with current one. I need to show whatever card i swipe it should display respective score of each card

source code for score screen where i have store the score in userdefaults and also the card id in userdefaults

```
self.progressScoreView.value = CGFloat(self.tempProgress)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.progressScoreView.value, forKey: "percent_completed")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.cardId, forKey: "card_ID")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

my home screen code where i am displaying score which is written in cellforrow method and i am checking saved card id with the id of the card coming from api side:

```
if let status = dict.cardStatus, let cardID = dict.cardId, status.count != 0
        {
            let card_completed_percent = UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "percent_completed")
            let tmpID = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "card_ID")
            print(tmpID)

            if status == "Unlock"
            {
                if card_completed_percent > 0 && (cardID == tmpID)
                {
                    let tmpCompleted = forTrailingZero(temp: card_completed_percent)
                    cell.percentCompleted.text = "\(tmpCompleted)%"
                    print(cell.percentCompleted.text!)
                    cell.deckLock.isHidden = true
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.percentCompleted.text = ""
                    print(cell.percentCompleted.text!)
                    cell.deckLock.isHidden = true
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cell.percentCompleted.text = ""
                cell.deckLock.isHidden = false
            }
        }
```

please help me with this problem

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is here:

```
let card_completed_percent = UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "percent_completed")
let tmpID = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "card_ID")
```

i that way you only save one percent value at all.
try this: 
UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "percent_completed_food") and
UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "percent_completed_other_category") 
so that you save one value for each category.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving your percent and card ID like

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(self.progressScoreView.value, forKey: "percent_completed_for_\(category.id)")
UserDefaults.standard.set(self.cardId, forKey: "card_ID\(card.id)")
```

and get values from UserDefaults with these keys.